# How to overwrite jqGrid's language defaults?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Assuming I can't change the language file because I want the defaults to keep the same except for this particular case.

I want to change the caption for the edit form. Assume as well that there are going to be other grids that will use different captions for that same edit form.

So far, I know that the edit form is launched calling this method:

```
grid.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowID, {properties});
```

In the Documentation Wiki, you can find a paragraph about this that says:

> These options can be overwritten when passed as options to the method.
>   When passed to the method we should use by example bSubmit : “Submit”
>   and not $.jgrid.edit.bSubmit : “Submit”

But it doesn't say *what* method to which I have to pass the options. 'editGridRow' doesn't have an options parameter, and if I pass it as a property like so:

```
grid.jqGrid('editGridRow', rowID, { editCaption: "My Edit Caption" });
```

it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your solution should work, but lets just try this out.

```
    $.jgrid.nav.addtext = "Add";
    $.jgrid.nav.edittext = "Edit";
    $.jgrid.nav.deltext = "Delete";
    $.jgrid.edit.addCaption = "Add Me";
    $.jgrid.edit.editCaption = "Edit Me";
```

you can over ride them like this, include this under your script tag before jQGrid Code, it's not tested though.

Comment: Well, that works. This will just affect the grid that is being built during those statements?

Comment: if you use this on a single page, so only on that page it will over ride the properties of jqgrid.